# 2-stage loops failing to compile

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble understanding why VBA failed to compile here. I tried different changes, but the compile error turned to different errors. I'm trying to set the vardate as a date and varfund to fund so I can link it up to an updated Bloomberg formula (that part works). Can anyone help? Thanks

```
Sub Test()

Dim lastdate As Date
Dim Raw As Worksheet
Set Raw = Sheets("Raw")

lastdate = Raw.Range("A3")

'If lastdate < Date And Date - lastdate < 51 Then
    'Do Until lastdate = Date
       ' lastdate = lastdate + 1
        'If Weekday(lastdate, vbMonday) < 6 Then
         '   Rows(3).Insert
           ' Raw.Range("A3") = lastdate
      '  End If
 '   Loop
'End If


'=BDH($B$1, "PX_LAST", $A$13, $A$13)  <-- Base formula

Dim vardate As Date
Dim varfund As String

Dim i As Integer 'Rows
Dim j As Integer 'Columns

For i = 1 To 50
    For j = 1 To 100
        vardate = Raw.Cells.Value(i + 2, 1) 'Defines the new date
        varfund = Raw.Cells.Text(1, j + 1) 'Defines the fund variables
        
        If Raw.Cells.Formula(i + 2, j + 1) = "" And varfund <> "" Then
        Raw.Cells.Formula(i + 2, j + 1) = "=BDH(" & varfund & "," & Chr(34) & _
        "PX_LAST" & Chr(34) & ", " & vardate & ", " & vardate & ")"
        End If
        
    Next j
Next i
                
            
End Sub
```

Comment: the .Value method does not take parameters, it just returns a value.  the '(i+2,1)' should be associated with the Cell object as in 'Raw.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value'.  You have similar errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: It works, thanks so much. Can you please explain why in this situation, putting value before worked, but in this case it didn't?

Comment: You need to gain a better understanding  of the object model you are using. This is as simple as putting the cursor on a keyword and pressing F1. This will bring up the MS help page on that keyword. If that fails try pressing F2 to bring up the object browser. If you don't understand either of these instructions Dr you shouldn't really be trying to use VBA.

Comment: `Cells` documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells. If you are not familiar with the object you are dealing with, always consult the documentation.

Comment: @freeflow I didn't know of these functions before! This will be a lifesaver since I usually just google the stuff (and usually their code is just patched together). I've only recently started to code it from scratch (since my use cases have started becoming esotheric). I'll definitely make use of this

Comment: @RaymondWu The F1 function goes directly to the documentation! Thank you